# Why is my code working fine when running in the console but not when used in the script?

Tags: python, file-handling

When I tried the following code in my IDE and in the command prompt with `python test.py`, my text file was still empty afterward:

```
with open("test.txt", "r+") as file:
    file.write("Hello World")
```

I was confused, because this worked before. So I tried the exact same code in the python console.
And voila, my text file `test.txt` now contained the string `Hello World`

When I changed the content of the text file manually and tried to read it again with the program, the output was the string I tried to write earlier to the text file.

Is there some kind of delay when trying to write and read to and from a file when using a script in comparison to using the python console?

Comment: I suspect that the current working directory is different between your two scenarios, so you're dealing with two entirely different `text.txt` files, in different directories.

Comment: I believe the cmd is located somewhere else, so you actually created two files.

Comment: @jasonharper I just opened the python console in my current working folder and tried it again. The console input altered my original test.txt as I wanted. Afterward, I tried the same with the script and it failed to write and to read. Is there something wrong with how I try to open the text file inside my script? It is still the same code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the cmd is located somewhere else.

You can change the location of where you are operating in the cmd with the os module:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.chdir(path) # replace path with the path you want to write to a file in
>>> with open('text.txt','r+') as file:
...     file.write("Hello World")
...
>>>
```

You can also find the current directory of your cmd by entering `os.getcwd()`. Or, you can just add the path of the place you want to write in the file to the file name:

```
>>> import os
>>> with open(os.path.join(path,'text.txt'),'r+') as file:
...     file.write("Hello World")
...
>>>
```

Comment: @AnnZen I tried exactly this and the other recommended approach and when I tried to read the text file, the script returned the string "this is a test input", which I tried to write to the file earlier. It really seems like there are two different files, but I don't understand where the second one is supposed to be located. Also after I added in the complete path like you suggested.

Comment: @AnnZen I just checked everything and I am 100% sure that I'm in the correct path with my script. It rather seems that there is a hidden copy of the text file that the script is trying to access. Do you have any further ideas? Thank you for your effort

Comment: @AnnZen Yes, sure I do. How could I have opened the python script otherwise? I am at the right location, but the text file I am trying to access within the same folder doesn't seem to be the same file I can access via the python console in the same folder. The must be some kind of invisible copy, that the script uses.

Comment: Try entering ```os.getcwd()``` in your cmd

Answer (score 0):

Try pass the absolute path of the file.

It should be like this

```
with open("/the/path/test.txt", "r+") as file:
    file.write("Hello World")
```